# как получить значение цикла при котором сработал листнер

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Нужна помощь, пока зеленый в скрипте. Прошу помощи.

код

```js
for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    items[i].addEventListener('click', addclass);
    var a = i;
    
    function addclass(){
        for(number = 0; number < items.length; number++){
        items[number].classList.remove('active-items');
        content[number].classList.remove('activeItems');
    }
        items[a].classList.add('active-items');
        content[a].classList.add('activeItems');
    }

}
```

прошу не бросаться тапками, если вопрос нубский. Сам пока нуб.
нужно значение [i] при котором сработал листнер, передать в [a]
Заранее благодарю

---

благодарю за наводку про "Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?"
попробовал листнер вкинуть в анонимную функцию, но он там к сожалению запускаться не хотел
вот код - может чего неправильно делаю

```js
function cn(){ console.log('click')}

for(var int=0; int<items.length; int++){
(function(int){items[int].addEventListener('click', cn)});
```

в таком варианте на клик реакции нет. Надеюсь гуру дадут пинок в нужном направлении. Сори за наглость, ранее программирование не изучал. В теме только пару недель. Так что за тупливо прошу прощение.

Теперь изложу суть своего творения

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.featuresAside__items');
var content = document.querySelectorAll('.NoactiveItems');

function cn(){ console.log('click')}



for(var int=0; int<items.length; int++){
(function(int){items[int].addEventListener('click', cn)});
    
    
    function addclass(){
        for(number = 0; number < items.length; number++){
        items[number].classList.remove('active-items');
        content[number].classList.remove('activeItems');
    }
        items[int].classList.add('active-items');
        content[int].classList.add('activeItems');
    }

}
```

есть группа элементов(типа вкладки), при клик на который у соседей удаляется класс выделение. На тот который кликнули применяется класс выделения. Контент меняется в зависимости от нажатой вкладки. Поэтому мне необходимо отследить на каком элементе произошел клик(на каком по щету в масиве) для того чтоб именно ему присвоить клас выделение и контент(в своем массиве- такой же по щету) присвоить клас отображения контента. 
Вот такая у меня стоит задача, если кто то сможет обяснить что к чему, буду премного благодарен. Возможно я просто выбрал не ту стратегию.
`
Всем спасибо кто откликнулся. Заработало

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.featuresAside__items');
var content = document.querySelectorAll('.NoactiveItems');


for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    (function(i){
    items[i].addEventListener('click', (function() {addclass(i)}));
    })(i);
     
    function addclass(a){
        for(number = 0; number < items.length; number++){
        items[number].classList.remove('active-items');
        content[number].classList.remove('activeItems');
    }
        items[a].classList.add('active-items');
        content[a].classList.add('activeItems');
        console.log(a);
    }

}
```

только в таком виде добился необходимого результата. Мозг кипит))
`
переписал код по другому

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.featuresAside__items');
const content = document.querySelectorAll('.NoactiveItems');


for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    
    items[i].addEventListener('click', addclass);
    
    function addclass(){
        for(number = 0; number < items.length; number++){
        items[number].classList.remove('active-items');
        content[number].classList.remove('activeItems');
    }
        items[i].classList.add('active-items');
        content[i].classList.add('activeItems');
    }
}
```

Безценный опыт получен. i'm happy)))

Comment: Вы когда код копируете\воспроизводите - делайте это аккуртано. В программировании каждая точка\скобка важна. Посмотрите еще раз *внимательно* на пример с анонимной функцией.

Comment: достаточно было заменить `var` на `let` и все бы заработало.

Comment: @Grundy - огромное спасибо. Еще учится и учится. Чем больше понимаешь, тем больше чувство что ничего не понимаешь)))))